# Where to find "Tiles" Design on Homepages in the wild

Tags: homepage, sliders

Recently I stumbled over a Homepage which had a sort of tiled design on the homepage consisting of several black/dark rounded boxes positioned next to each other. Similar to stack exchange view all sites, but with just a few boxes of different size above the fold.

However I forgot which site it was, and am now looking for successful implementations of that design in the wild and possibly if there is a name for this other than tiles?

(Tiles seems to be something slightly different, involving functionality)

This is how it looks like:

[image]

The aim here is to replace a slider with something like that.

So basically I am asking if this design has a name, and what well known websites use it on their homepage instead of a slider (news sites don't count).

Comment: It looks like simply fitting rectangles into a page.  What comes to my mind is "newspaper layout" but that's not an established term for a layout style.  Can you give us more clues as to what you're after beyond this general idea?

Comment: I need to present several things on the homepage. Marketing msges, webinar, maybe news, etc but I dont want to use a slider. A news homepage has however very specific needs, so I don't want to look at news homepages.

Comment: Basically im looking for established brochure type websites, who do not use a slider but still have various msges above the fold, and maybe these rectangles have a name as design pattern?

Comment: It's fairly common to have diverse units of functionality arranged in tight fitting rectangles on a page. I don't think there's a specific style or pattern that applies.

Comment: How are you differentiating between the grid style design (that is often associated with web pages) and the tile style design (that seems to be associated with apps)? I think the real difference is in the interaction and not the layout, and it would probably be impractical for websites to have the Windows 8 style of interaction.

Comment: When you say slider, do you mean carousel?

Comment: yes carousel @Lai grid design may be more apropriate, i am tlking strictly about layout. Although grid for me at least means something slightly different (eg table with straight horizontal and vertical lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These sites are similar.

1. http://www.istockphoto.com
2. http://flipboard.com (used on app but not
   website)
3. And jQuery **Masonry** is the js plugin used to make the "Tiles" Design. They have a showcase of sites using it.  http://masonry.desandro.com

Comment: masonry seems to be the right idea.

Comment: Glad to help. Let me know if mine is the best answer.

Comment: yours is the only answer so far - so it is the best, the worst and everything else as well ;)